# Wrong width and height when reusing FileReader

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filereader, jcrop

I am currently developing a simple interface allowing users to upload a picture, have a preview of it, and then be able to crop it as a square.

I'm using FileReader to get the preview of the image, and jCrop to crop it.

Here is the code I'm using (a part of it):

```
    var jcrop = null;
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {

            $('#upload-picture-sample').attr('src', e.target.result).load(function(){
                var img = this;

                var imageWidth = img.width;
                var imageHeight = img.height;

                console.log(img.width+'-- WIDTH --'+$(this).width());
                console.log(img.height+'-- HEIGHT --'+$(this).height());

                if(imageWidth != imageHeight){

                    var selectArray = [];

                    if(imageWidth > imageHeight){
                        selectArray = [(imageWidth-imageHeight)/2, 0, (imageWidth-imageHeight)/2 + imageHeight, imageHeight];
                    }else{
                        selectArray = [0, (imageHeight - imageWidth)/2, imageWidth, (imageHeight - imageWidth)/2 + imageWidth];
                    }
                    if(!jcrop){
                        $('#upload-picture-sample').Jcrop({
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            keySupport: false,
                            addClass: 'jcrop-centered',
                            setSelect: selectArray
                        }, function(){
                            jcrop = this;
                        });
                    }else{
                        jcrop.setImage(e.target.result);
                        jcrop.setSelect(selectArray);

                    }
                }
                $(this).unbind('load');
            });   
        }

    $('#upload-picture-file').change(function(){
        $('#upload-picture-send').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#upload-picture-error').hide();

        console.log('changed!');

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    })
```

I think the only part that really matters is the part when I calculate the width and height.

To illustrate the problem, I'm uploading:

1/ Picture1 (600x450)

2/ Picture2 (94x125)

3/ Picture1 again (600x450)

[image]

The first upload is working fine, the second is working fine as well, but I guess it's more luck than something else, since the height is incorrectly calculated as 0.
The third upload is not working (the size is not correctly set).

It means that the cropzone is not correctly displayed.

Regarding css, I have this:

```
#upload-picture-sample{
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  max-height:125px;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  max-width:300px;
}
```

Do you have any idea of how I could solve my problem?

UPDATE: After having added `setTimeout` as recommended by @initialxy
[image]

So it's much better, but still, the first image doesn't have the same dimensions than the last (and it should, since it's exactly the same image)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your numbers look inconsistent. In first image, width end up being 167 with `img.width` but 167 with jQuery. One thing to note is that jQuery gets [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) while `img.width` and `img.height` are DOM properties that sets desired width and height. (FYI there's also `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`, which are read-only DOM properties that gets you the original dimensions of `img`.)

> it's more luck than something else

If your code depends on luck, then we got a problem.

It looks like browser emitted load event slightly too early, such that layout engine hasn't finished updating the DOM. `load` just means data is loaded, doesn't necessarily mean layout engine has to be completed. So try to queue your code block inside your load function later in the task queue. By which, I mean wrap all that in a `setTimeout(..., 0);` Watch out for `this`, as it has changed.

eg.

```
$('#upload-picture-sample').attr('src', e.target.result).load(function(){
    var img = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        var imageWidth = img.width;
        var imageHeight = img.height;

        console.log(img.width+'-- WIDTH --'+$(img).width());
        console.log(img.height+'-- HEIGHT --'+$(img).height());

        // TODO: Crop
        ...
    }, 0);

    $(this).unbind('load');
});
```

**EDIT:** In response to @Vico's update. Looks like layout engine has settled this time. Let's make some observations on these numbers. The first image's dimensions were originally 600x450, but it ended up being 167x125. This makes sense, because it was resized by `max-height: 125px;` CSS property. The second image has both of its dimensions less than `max-width` and `max-height` so it didn't get resized. The third image has dimensions of 600x450, and it ended up having these dimensions, so at this point `max-width` and `max-height` is no longer taking effect. Why is that? Perhaps jcrop screwed around with style and overridden your style. Fire up your Chrome debugger, inspect your `img` element and use its JavaScript console to play around with it. (To give you a short answer, yes, jcrop does screw around with style and applies inline styles to the element, which overrides your style. But hey, it's more fun to play with debugger.) Also, I'm not sure why your dimensions on the right all ended up with 1440x514. You can find out by screwing around in debugger.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @initialxy, I have updated my post to show the new results.

Nevertheless, I still have a weird result for the last upload. Any clue?

Comment: Thanks for your update @initialxy. What is weird is that the images are correctly sized. The jcrop one, and the original one (upload-picture-sample). When I check with the inspector, everything seems fine. So else the width and height values are wrong, else I get their size BEFORE css is applied.

Comment: @Vico You are using the same element for both measuring the image size as well as letting jcrop use it. jscrop applied bunch of inline styles to it. Open your debugger and select your __original__ `img` in inspector. (Now in JavaScript console, you can conveniently refer to it with `$0` by the way.) What do you see? Something like `<img id="upload-picture-sample" src="..." style="display: none; visibility: hidden; width: 1440px; height: 514px;">` isn't it? Notice the `style` attribute has bunch of unwanted values to it?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. But in fact, the values are correct:
"display: none; visibility: hidden; width: 167px; height: 125px;"

Comment: In console, run `$0.width` and `$0.height` what do you see? Edit its inline styles, remove `display: none; visibility: hidden;` and try again `$0.width`, `$0.height` what do you see? Finally remove `width: 1440px; height: 514px;` and try again, what do you see?

Comment: These values are added by jcrop and they overrides the behaviours of your CSS. They are screwing up your width and height.

Comment: Wow, you were right! Adding `$('#upload-picture-sample').attr('style', '');` before `$('#upload-picture-sample').attr('src', e.target.result).load(function(){}` solved the issue! 
I also have to add `$('#upload-picture-sample').hide();` if jcrop was defined.
Well done and thank you a lot for your expertise!

Answer (score 0):

For more information, I suggest all the potential readers to have a look at this issue:
https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/issues/46

The workarounds work fine.